# Netlogo Flocking Model Code Explanation

Tags: math, netlogo

I'm investigating the flocking model of netlogo. It has the following code that is strange. What does this code do ***mathematically***? 
If I would see this in mathematical notations I would understand this. I suppose this is how trigonometry gets implemented in netlogo ?

```
to heading
  turn-towards average-heading max-align-turn
end

to-report average-heading
  let x-component sum [dx] of flock
  let y-component sum [dy] of flock
  ifelse x-component = 0 and y-component = 0
    [ report heading ]
    [ report atan x-component y-component ]
end

to turn-towards [new-heading max-turn]
  turn-at-most (subtract-headings new-heading heading) max-turn
end

to turn-at-most [turn max-turn]
  ifelse abs turn > max-turn
    [ ifelse turn > 0
        [ rt max-turn ]
        [ lt max-turn ] ]
    [ rt turn ]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
to-report average-heading
  let x-component sum [dx] of flock
  let y-component sum [dy] of flock
 ifelse x-component = 0 and y-component = 0
   [ report heading ]
   [ report atan x-component y-component ]
end
```

[dy and dy](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dict/dxy.html) are the sine and cosine of the turtles headings so what we are looking at is

The procedure reports 
The arctangent of the sum of the sines of the turtle-headings , sum of the cosines of the turtle-headings.

it is so the mean heading of the set of angles obviously if we just up the headings and divide by the number of turtles we end up with a lot of problems.

Comment: So this gives a mean heading?

Comment: I am sorry. Yes this gives the mean heading,

Comment: Ok, thanks. This code seems to implement the mean of circular quantities? I missed the atan argument